# Request for which the user visited the site

Tags: php, request, web

How can I find out by what request the user came to the site from the browser?

I need to generate a page based on the request.

User's request example: "buy motocycle XXXX-74". then browser displays N sites (one of them mine) and user goes to my site.

And how I can get this request? ""buy motocycle XXXX-74""

Comment: What do you mean by `request`? Request method like POST GET or request params?

Comment: You definitely need to provide more info on your question to be able to help.

Comment: @AbrahamA.
updated

Comment: @PriyeshKumar updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still not super clear but I think that might be either language or lack of technology lingo.

But I think what you want is to have PHP do something based on either GET or POST variables sent to a page.

You could have the receiving PHP file with a switch case to do different things based on the GET or POST request. 
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php